# Ruby array contains types?

Tags: ruby

I need a function to check if an array contains other arrays, or more generally if an array contains a certain class. My naive first approach is:

```
found=false
[1,"a",[],:asdf].each { |x| found=(x.is_a? Array) ? true : found }
puts found
```

Any way to optimize this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In newer Rubies (`2.5+`) you don't need to pass a block to [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F). That links goes to the latest docs, which has a similar example checking for integers.

Therefore, you can simply use:

```
[1, "a", [], :asdf].any?(Array)
# => true

[1, "a", :asdf].any?(Array)
# => false
```

That seems the simplest syntax and most sensible approach here if your Ruby version allows it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try [#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-any-3F)

For example:

```
[1,"a",[],:asdf].any? { |el| el.is_a? Array }
#=> true
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost always when you find yourself using `each`, you are missing some higher-level abstraction.

In this case, that abstraction is the method [`Array#any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-any-3F), which will return `true` if any element of the array satisfies the predicate:

```rb
[1, "a", [], :asdf].any?(Array)
```

Comment: Your edit makes your answer the same as @SRack's earlier answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, this is one of the ways he farms his reputation for all these years.

Comment: @Nakilon, we are fortunate to have Mr. Mittag. I've learned a lot from him.

Answer (score 1):

this approach iterate over all elements even if you found an array.
in your test case it will iterate over **:asdf**, 
and you don't have to check this.

I think you need to break from loop if you found the certain type(Array in our Example).

```
found = false
[1,"a",[],:asdf].each do |x|
    if x.is_a? Array
     found = true
     break
    end
end

puts found
```

Also you can use **any** instead of **each**

```
found = [1,"a",[],:asdf].any? { |x| x.is_a? Array }
puts found # true
```

Comment: That edit makes this a copy of @AlexGolubenko's answer :(